# How can I discover the Python version in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, versioning

Where can I discover the Python version installed in QGIS 2.18.1?

I would like to buy a book to introduce me at Python interface. I've found one that addresses the version 3.3 of Python.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Alongside sys.version_info, as mentioned above, you can use

```
import sys
sys.version
```

sys.version_info will give this kind of output (this comes from my copy of QGIS 2.18.1):

```
>>> import sys

>>> sys.version_info

sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

sys.version will give the version number, alongside the compiler used:

```
>>> import sys

>>> sys.version

'2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]'
```

Answer (score 17):

Looks like in QGIS v3.0, python v3 will be implemented:

[Help us to plan for QGIS 3.0](http://blog.qgis.org/2016/01/17/help-us-to-plan-for-qgis-3-0/)

> Updating Python 2.7 to Python 3: Currently we bundle in Python 2.7 in
>   our windows installers and require 2.7 on other platforms where we do
>   not co-bundle Python with QGIS. Python 3 is the latest version of
>   python and is recommended by the Python project. Python 2 is slightly
>   incompatible with Python 3 (in much the same way as QGIS 2 -> QGIS 3
>   will be incompatible). The python developers have made Python 3
>   largely backwards compatible to Python 2, but the compatibility in the
>   opposite direction is not as good.

Here is the syntax you may run in the python console in QGIS to verify version:

```
import sys
print sys.version_info
```

Comment: Givent that QGIS 3.0 will be released in the next months, it's probably still worth considering to directly start learning python 3.

Comment: Thanks artwork21 and Matthias Kuhn! Your information were very helpful. My actual version is 2.7.5, but I´m gonna start learning Python 3 and wait the next version.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to know what version of python you are using can be to run the following command on the python console that has QGIS:

```
from platform import python_version
print(python_version())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Since QGIS 3.20](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/45a9309afa124d99715f8fd44a06dc4777823660) you can use the `Help > About` to see the Python version.

[image: example]

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not see anything related to Python version under `Help > About` in my QGIS 3.18. I see: QGIS version, Compiled against Qt, Compiled against GDAL/OGR, Compiled against GEOS, Compiled against SQLite, PostgreSQL Client Version, QWT Version, Compiled against PROJ, OS Version, Active python plugins, QGIS code revision, Running against Qt, Running against GDAL/OGR, Running against GEOS, Running against SQLite, SpatiaLite Version, QScintilla2 Version, Running against PROJ.

Comment: It's in 3.20 https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/45a9309afa124d99715f8fd44a06dc4777823660